# How to solve HackerRank problems in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Can anybody explain how to give the hacker rank test in objective-C. Specially the part "Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT"

How to read input and out in objective-c ?

What i have got so far is get input like

```
 NSFileHandle *fileHandler = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput];
 NSData *inputData = [fileHandler availableData];
 NSString *inputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:inputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But to print output, following does not print anything on HackerRank console (but works flawlessly on Xcode console)

```
NSFileHandle* fileHandler=[NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardOutput];
[fileHandler writeData: [formattedString dataUsingEncoding: NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest possible way to "Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT" would be to use scanf and printf.
 
Here's a ***sample template*** to get you started:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    int count;
    scanf("%d", &count);
    NSMutableArray *inputIntegers = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        int inputElement;
        scanf("%d", &inputElement);
        [inputIntegers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:inputElement]];
    }

    //to print a specific element:
    printf("printing element 0: %d", (int)[inputIntegers[0] integerValue]);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Before you take a shot at this journey, a few things:

- Make sure ARC is disabled (search for CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC in build settings, and set it to NO)
- Avoid using **self**. This is functional programming.
- Use C functions, not Objective-C methods, meaning, use

instead of

```
 - (NSInteger)sumOfNumbers : (NSInteger)a and:(NSInteger)b {
    return a + b;
}
```

use

```
int sumOfNumbers(int a, int b){

    return a + b;
}
```

Happy Programming.

Comment: I m totally confused on how to solve even a simple problem in hackerrank using Objective C. I tried a sample test in hackerrank which had this staircase problem. I am baffled on how to get the value of n in SolutionClass, how to print the value to check whether it is working, how to execute and how to print the output. I tried searching web and I couldn't understand it properly. If someone can redirect me in right direction, show a sample tutorial, video tutorial link of solving some problem, will be of great help. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it will fail if I replace "printf" with "NSLog". Why?

Comment: what about several strings in separate lines?

Comment: @allenlinli because NSLog isn't STDOUT.  @Zangetsu use `\n` to separate lines

Answer (score 3):

Having just been handed one of these tests, I opted to get out of main.m immediately and into Objective-C like so:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//Objective-C helper class to take over from main.m

//.h
@interface MainClass : NSObject

+ (BOOL)startMain;

@end

//.m
@implementation MainClass

+ (BOOL)startMain {

    //Read the STDIN here using the Objective-C wrapper methods
    NSInteger n = [self readInt];

    [self printInt:n];

    NSArray *numbers = [self readIntArrayOfLength:n];

    [self printIntNumberArray:numbers];

    return YES;
}

+ (NSInteger)readInt {

    int n;

    scanf("%i",&n);

    return n;
}

+ (NSArray *)readIntArrayOfLength:(NSInteger)len {

    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i =0; i < len; i++) {

        [result addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[self readInt]]];
    }

    return [result copy];
}

//Helpers to print an int and array of ints to STDOUT
+ (void)printInt:(NSInteger)i {

    printf("%li\n",(long)i);
}

+ (void)printIntNumberArray:(NSArray *)array {

    printf("[");

    [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *n, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

        printf("%li",(long)[n integerValue]);

        if (idx < array.count-1) {
            printf(",");
        }
    }];

    printf("]\n");
}

@end

//This is what will actually run when you hit "Run Code"
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {
        return [MainClass startMain];
    }
}
```

Now you can do whatever you like from here using Objective-C.

So in this example a sample input of:

```
3
11 2 4
```

Would produce this output:

```
3
[11,2,4]
```

Not useful in of itself but illustrates the successful read.

It's a lot simpler in Swift, but here's code to accomplish the same thing anyway:

```
func readInt() -> Int? {

    if let ln = readLine() {
        return Int(ln)
    }

    return nil
}

func readIntArray() -> [Int]? {

     if let ln = readLine() {

        return ln.characters.split(" ").filter({ Int(String($0)) != nil }).map({ Int(String($0))! })
    }

    return nil
}

let n = readInt()!
let array = readIntArray()!

print(n)
print(array)
```

The functions return optionals because even though you are going to force-unwrap the input, better the crash for a nil optional happens in your code than the boilerplate.

Comment: `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` were available, no problem? They make working with some of the questions a whole lot easier than using just raw C arrays.

Answer (score 2):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> 

int sum(int a, int b) {
   return a + b;
}

int main() {
   @autoreleasepool {
      int T;
      int A;
      int B;
      printf("Enter number of test cases: ");
      scanf("%d", &T);
      for (int i=0; i < T; i++) {
          scanf("%d", &A);
          scanf("%d", &B);
          printf("%d\n", sum(A,B));
      }
     }
   return 0;
}
```

That ought to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really too general for SO, do not be surprised if it gets closed soon. You need in general to ask specific questions, show what you've tried, etc. But if you're just after a few hints to get you going...

You don't say whether you are a programmer already or know Objective-C in particular, assuming both:

1. In Xcode look at the Command Line Tool project type
2. Look into `NSFileHandle` and its methods, e.g. `fileHandleWithStandardInput`
3. Note you can also use the C stdio functions, converting C-style to Objective-C styles strings etc. as needed.

Comment: yes i agree. May be i was thinking that someone has successfully submitted a solution and share just the input and output mechanism. I am editing the question with more explanation.

Comment: The [example problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/environment/sample-problem) on HackerRank uses C stdio functions, maybe you should try those?

Comment: Yes looks like that's the only way. Will wait for few days for any other alternative (as was just curious for any other alternative) than will close the question.

Answer (score 0):

I created github repo with some hackerrank problem solutions written in objective-c. It is on the beginning stage, feel free to contribute by adding your solutions as well.

[HackerRank for Objective-C](https://github.com/aatalyk/HackerRank-Objective-C-Solutions)

Answer (score 0):

Since Objective-C is a superset of C, you can use C methods for reading and printing out:

```
NSInteger n;
char *input[25];
NSMutableArray *strings = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *s;
NSString *temp;

scanf("%lu", &n);

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    scanf("%s", input);
    s = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:input];
    [inputs addObject:s];
}
```

If **n** is of type **int**, you can read it as:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```